# Will it ever be possible to use wrapfig with an enumerate or itemize environment?

Tags: lists, wrapfigure

[`wrapfig`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf) is incompatible with the `enumerate` and `itemize` environments. Is there a typographical reason not to wrap a list around a figure or is it a technical limitation of LaTeX? If it is a technical limitation, is there any work (new packages or changes to LaTeX) currently being done to eliminate the limitation in the future?

**Edit**: To respond to some of the comments: I realize that there are "gymnastics" which can make this work. I do not have an example of the problem. Whenever I run into a problem with wrapfig because it is near an enumerate or itemize environment, I search for an easy solution, find none, and move the figure elsewhere. In the vast majority of cases, the cost of learning the complex solutions isn't worth the benefit of keeping the figure where I want it.

Comment: I have some thoughts for LaTeX3: currently we still need to do work on this, but I would expect `13galley` to eventually cover this.

Comment: Another solution to having cutouts in latex lists is given here

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53702/wrapping-text-in-enumeration-environment-around-a-table/53715#53715

Comment: @JosephWright Do you have a link with more information about `13galley`?

Comment: @student http://texdoc.net/pkg/xgalley and http://texdoc.net/pkg/l3galley would be a start

Comment: @JosephWright Your first comment that `13galley` would eventually help is from 2012. Is there any progress since then regarding the question? Or even better a production ready solution?

Comment: @student `l3galley` can only really work as part of a new format: whilst it will help at the present that's only in carefully set-up tests. Bruno Le Floch is intending to see if we can 'force' the code to work with existing formats but I'm doubtful.

Comment: @JosephWright What do you mean by "new format" in this case?

Comment: @JosephWright I’m also curious about how this is progressing. I like to let text wrap around figures, and `wrapfigure` is far too inflexible for this purpose. My tests of `xgalley` were very promising until I realized it created wrong *vertical* spacing around lists. Is there any hope this can be fixed to make the package useful within LaTeX2e?

Answer (score 26):

FWIW, wrapfigure works out of the box in ConTeXt. So, it is clearly not a limitation of TeX.

```
\setuppapersize[A5]

\useexternalfigure[ctanlion][http://www.ctan.org/lion/ctan_lion_350x350.png][width=3cm]


\starttext

\placefigure[left,2*hang]{Test}
  {\externalfigure[ctanlion]}

\startitemize[n]
  \item \input ward
  \item \input ward
  \item \input ward
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

which gives:

[image]

Removing `2*hang` from `\placefigure` gives:

[image]

Comment: +1: This is a really nice example for ConTeXt's simplicity.

Comment: What if I want to use a figure from a png file in the directory?

Comment: @MarcoDisce: Just use `\externalfigure[filename.png]`. See [using graphics](https://www.contextgarden.net/Using_Graphics) on ConTeXt wiki for more details.

Answer (score 24):

The [`cutwin`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cutwin) package (and some `\parshape` gymnastics) can be used here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{%
  \hspace*{25pt}\includegraphics[height=4cm]{ctanlion}
  \captionof{figure}{A test figure.}
}
\opencutleft

\begin{cutout}{2}{10pt}{0.5\linewidth}{12}
\begin{enumerate}
{%
\parshape 15 26pt \linewidth 26pt \linewidth 0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth
  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth
  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth   0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth   0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth 
  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth   0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth   0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth
  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth   0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth 26 pt \linewidth
\item \lipsum[1]
}%
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{cutout}

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Comment: This should even work if you want to put the picture at the start of the numbering. I didn't try it with `cutwin`, but just an ordinary `\parshape`.

Comment: @Werner you're probably right; I used `cutwin` to put the figure after some lines of the numbering; right now I have to leave, but I will do some tests later and post some code if no one else has done it.

Comment: If this is a good, general solution to the problem, would it be possible to develop a package which makes it possible to do this as few of lines of code as `wrapfig`? Could wrapfig be modified to use this alternative approach when used in a list?

Comment: Your minimal working example (cut win package) fails if one uses a different font, say `\usepackage{palatino}`.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi yes, obviously it fails, because wrapping is related to font dimensions, that's why the packages like `cutwin` and `wrapfig` do exist, but in some cases, they cannot be used. The same problem can arise if the text contains inline math which changes the real baseline distance...

Comment: @tohecs:unliike `cutwin`, `wrapfig` does not fail.

Comment: cutwin doesn't seem to come with ubuntu, any way I can install it?

Comment: @RickyRobinson You can download the files from CTAN: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cutwin then you can extract the .sty file and place it somewhere TeX can find it. In this site there's some question/answers addressing manual installation of packages. You should consider installing a complete TeX Live system from TUG: http://www.tug.org/texlive/

Comment: what if you want to add two different figures inside the same `itemize`?

Answer (score 7):

It is possible by putting the wrapfigure into a `parbox` or `minipage` as is mentioned in some of the duplicates of this question. However those methods usually fix vertical spacing issues by manually inserting `\vspace` with hand picked values. This solution works automatically by using a strut. The `strut` places the baseline of the first text line at a specified distance from the top of the `minipage`. Then `adjustbox` is used to place the top of the `minipage` exactly that amount above the outer baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\strutheight}
\settoheight{\strutheight}{\strut}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \lipsum[1]
  \item
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T,raise=\strutheight,minipage={\linewidth}}
      \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
      \end{wrapfigure}
    \strut{}\lipsum[2]
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a kluge.  It replaces `itemize` with a lookalike, instead of trying to fiddle around with `wrapfig`.

```
\documentclass{article}

%put this code in preamble
\newlength{\bulletwidth}\settowidth{\bulletwidth}{$\bullet$}
\newcommand{\mitem}{\setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}\hspace*{-\labelsep}\hspace*{-\bulletwidth}$\bullet$\hspace*{\labelsep}}
\newcommand{\mend}{\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\mitem This is an example of a list item.

\mitem Second item in list.

\mend

Some more text.

\end{document}
```

Each `\mitem` in the list must be preceded by a blank line.  The list ends with `\mend` (also preceded by a blank line).  There's no command to begin the list. This works for simple text items; I haven't tried it with anything more complicated.

Someone who knows more about how `itemize` works (and why it conflicts with `wrapfig`) might be able to make an even better imitation.  It would also be fairly easy to generalize this to `enumerate`'d lists if necessary.

Comment: If each `\mitem` must start with a new paragraph, why not simply put a `\par` into its definition?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new wrap enviroment. In the following MWE my `wrapr` env. places the image in the right side of the page while `wrapl` place it in the left. Both enviroments have the same structure:

`wrapr{vertical adjustment of text}{number of lines}{horizontal space needed for the image}{vertical adjustment of image}{IMAGE}{TEXT}`

We can see here both enviroments in use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,tkz-euclide}
\tkzSetUpPoint[size=7,fill=white]
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\newenvironment{WrapText1}[3][r]
{\wrapfigure[#2]{#1}{#3}}
{\endwrapfigure}
\newenvironment{WrapText2}[3][l]
{\wrapfigure[#2]{#1}{#3}}
{\endwrapfigure}
\newcommand{\wrapr}[6]{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\mbox{}\\
\vspace{#1}
\begin{WrapText1}{#2}{#3}
\vspace{#4}#5\end{WrapText1}#6
\end{minipage}}

\newcommand{\wrapl}[6]{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\mbox{}\\
\vspace{#1}
\begin{WrapText2}{#2}{#3}
\vspace{#4}#5\end{WrapText2}#6
\end{minipage}}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\wrapr{-4mm}{8}{4cm}{5mm}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(1,2){A}
\tkzDefPoint(1.33,.66){G}
\tkzDefPoint(1.5,0){M}
\tkzDefPoint(.5,1){N}
\tkzDefPoint(2,1){P}
\draw(A)--(B)--(C)-- cycle;
\draw(A)--(M);
\draw(B)--(P);
\draw(C)--(N);
\tkzLabelPoint[left](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](M){$D$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](P){$E$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](N){$Z$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](C){$C$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left,yshift=-3mm,xshift=1.7mm](G){$G$}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M,N,P,G)
\end{tikzpicture}}{\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}}
\vspace{2cm}
\wrapl{-4mm}{8}{3cm}{5mm}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(1,2){A}
\tkzDefPoint(1.33,.66){G}
\tkzDefPoint(1.5,0){M}
\tkzDefPoint(.5,1){N}
\tkzDefPoint(2,1){P}
\draw(A)--(B)--(C)-- cycle;
\draw(A)--(M);
\draw(B)--(P);
\draw(C)--(N);
\tkzLabelPoint[left](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](M){$D$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](P){$E$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](N){$Z$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](C){$C$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left,yshift=-3mm,xshift=1.7mm](G){$G$}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M,N,P,G)
\end{tikzpicture}}{\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}}
\end{document}
```

[image]