# wrapfigure with enumerate

Tags: wrapfigure

I would like to use a `wrapfigure` with `enumerate`. But it doesn't work.
With this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
And now let's do a little test
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=0em]
  {M &N\\
   M/N&\\};
  \path[-stealth,>=stealth]
    (m-1-1)edge node[left]{$p$} (m-2-1)
           edge node[above]{$f$}(m-1-2)
    (m-2-1)edge[dashed,->]node[below]{$\bar{f}$}(m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext[1]

\begin{enumerate}
\item\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=0em]
  {M  &N\\
   M/N&\\};
  \path[-stealth,>=stealth]
    (m-1-1)edge node[left]{$p$} (m-2-1)
           edge node[above]{$f$}(m-1-2)
    (m-2-1)edge[dashed,->]node[below]{$\bar{f}$}(m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext[1]
\item\blindtext[1]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

Now, with `cutwin` package and this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{%
\hspace*{25pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=0em]
  { M  &N\\
    M/N&\\};
  \path[-stealth,>=stealth]
    (m-1-1)edge node[left]{$p$} (m-2-1)
           edge node[above]{$f$}(m-1-2)
    (m-2-1)edge[dashed,->]node[below]{$\bar{f}$}(m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

}
\opencutleft

\begin{cutout}{2}{10pt}{0.5\linewidth}{12}
\begin{enumerate}
{%
\parshape 15 26pt \linewidth 26pt \linewidth 0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth
  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth
  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth   0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth   0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth 
  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth   0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth   0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth
  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth   0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth 26 pt \linewidth
\item \lipsum[1]
}%
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{cutout}
\end{document}
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: As stated in the docs (first page), `wrapfig` does not work into list environments. You might try to replicate the desired effect with minipages (if this is only for one figure), but the result might not be optimal.

Comment: In your code, what's the point of centering inside a wrapped figure that must be put on the left or the right side?

Comment: @Bernard he probably wants to center the tikzpicture inside the wrapped space, try to remove the first centering and see the difference.

Comment: Not with `wrapfig`, but a possible work-around with `cutwin` is possible: please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59106/3954.

Comment: I tried this Gonzalo, but I have the following error:

Package pgfbasematrix Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.

And I have the same error with the picins package

Comment: @chickpea Hard to say anything without the offending code. Please edit your question and add there a minimal version of your document allowing use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to reply you but it´s no possible for me. so I let you an .tex where I have use minipage enviroment to do any similar in a "non beautifull way" https://www.dropbox.com/s/betc8yhy56aq5f9/MetodoGraficoAlturas_ToGonzalo.tex

Answer (score 0):

Using the workaround with `cutwin` and `\parshape` I suggested in [Will it ever be possible to use wrapfig with an enumerate or itemize environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59101/will-it-ever-be-possible-to-use-wrapfig-with-an-enumerate-or-itemize-environment). you need to use `ampersand replacement` for your matrix and make some adjustments for the `\parshape` settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{%
\hspace*{25pt}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&]
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=0em]
  { M  \&N \\
    M/N \& \\};
  \path[-stealth,>=stealth]
    (m-1-1)edge node[left]{$p$} (m-2-1)
           edge node[above]{$f$}(m-1-2)
    (m-2-1)edge[dashed,->]node[below]{$\bar{f}$}(m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\opencutleft

\begin{cutout}{2}{0pt}{0.6\linewidth}{8}
\begin{enumerate}
{%
\parshape 11 26pt \linewidth 26pt \linewidth 0.4\linewidth 0.6\linewidth
  0.4\linewidth 0.6\linewidth   0.4\linewidth 0.6\linewidth 
  0.4\linewidth 0.6\linewidth   0.4\linewidth 0.6\linewidth   0.4\linewidth 0.6\linewidth
  0.4\linewidth 0.6\linewidth   0.4\linewidth 0.6\linewidth 26 pt \linewidth
\item \lipsum[1]
}%
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{cutout}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Gonsalo. I tried your solution with the `picins` package and it works too!

Comment: @chickpea You're welcome! Glad to hear it worked. Since this question is basically a duplicate of the linked one, and it has been already marked as such, I will delete this answer shortly.

Comment: My personal opinion is that it´s good similar questions, becauswe sometime therre are particular things or new solutions. It´s good punt the link with usefull info to a question.