# Wrapping text around a table in enumeration environment with cutout and parshape

Tags: tables, wrapfigure, wrap, parshape

I borrowed the code for my MWE from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59106/4821). I want to put the table to right side and have difficulty in understanding `parshape` command. What is the purpose of 15 `26pt\linewidth 26pt\linewidth 0.5\linewidth` in `parshape` command. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{%
  \hspace*{25pt}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}\\\toprule  
Header-1 & Header-1 & Header-1 \\\midrule
2 &3 & 5\\  \midrule
2 &3 & 5\\  \midrule
2 &3 & 5\\  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}

\opencutleft

\begin{cutout}{3}{10pt}{0.5\linewidth}{12}
\begin{enumerate}
{%
\parshape 15 26pt\linewidth 26pt\linewidth 0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth
  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth  0.5\linewidth    0.5\linewidth
  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth  0.5\linewidth    0.5\linewidth 
  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth  0.5\linewidth    0.5\linewidth
  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth  0.5\linewidth 0.5\linewidth  26pt\linewidth

\item \lipsum[1]

}%

\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]

\end{enumerate}

\end{cutout}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have another solution to wrap a figure or table in a list environment. It relies on the `insbox.tex` generic macros file. Upon this file, I build two commands, `\InsertListL` and `\ InsertListR` that take two mandatory and one optional argument and insert any (well, most of them) box in a list environment.

The arguments are:

- the number of lines that remain unindented (mandatory)
- the box that is to be wrapped (mandatory…)
- the number of supplementary lines that will be indented, used as a correction (optional)

It works well, except for the `first` inserted box, which overlaps the label. So I defined a work around in the form of a patch to the \item command, called `wrapitem`.

To insert a box, the commands have to be inserted `immediately after` the \item command. You can't use captions, and no more than 1 box per item paragraph — which seems sensible.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \input{insbox}
    \makeatletter
    \@InsertBoxMargin = 12pt
    \makeatother
    \usepackage{nccmath}
    \usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}

    \newcommand*{\wrapitem}{\apptocmd{\labelenumi}{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}\item\apptocmd{\labelenumi}{\hskip-\leftmargin}{}{}}
    %
    \newcommand{\InsertListL}[3][]{%
    \setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}\mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
    \InsertBoxL{#2}{#3}[#1]\par \hspace{\itemindent}
    }%
    \newcommand{\InsertListR}[3][]{%
    \mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}%
    \InsertBoxR{#2}{\hskip-\leftmargin#3\hskip\leftmargin}[#1]
    }%

    \begin{document}

    \newcommand\windowpagestuff{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    Header-1 & Header-1 & Header-1 \\
    \midrule
    2 &3 & 5\\
    \midrule
    2 &3 & 5\\
    \midrule
    2 &3 & 5\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    }

    \begin{enumerate}%

    \wrapitem%
    \InsertListL[2]{2}{\windowpagestuff}%
    \lipsum[1]

     \item
    \InsertListR[2]{0}{\windowpagestuff}
    \lipsum[2]

    \InsertListR{3}{\parbox{5cm}{
        \[ (a + b^{2} = a^{2} + 2ab + b^{2} ) \] }}%
    \lipsum[3]

    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Thanks @Bernad for your nice answer. Would you like to add the code? Thanks

Comment: OH! Sorry. I thought I had done it! Of course, I'll load it at once.