# wrapfig how to designate where the figure should come and of what size exactly

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

This is a general question.

I find that the wrapfigure environment is very tricky. It depends on where you put it and if you add things to the top part you can make a good wrapfig bad. I would like to know if there is a way to tell the environment to put a particular figure to be in a particular part of a particular page.

Comment: Not exactly, but a generic package such as `insbox` lets ins you insert about any box on the left or the right of a paragraph,  with a predefined number of lines of ‘normal’ length before the box is inserted.

Comment: would love to have more guidance about insbox

Answer (score 1):

`insbox` is a set of generic macros that allow to insert (almost) any box (graphic file, equation, …) on the left ot the right of a paragraph. The two main commands are `\InsertBoxL{n}{boxcontent}[correction]` and `\InsertBoxR{n}{boxcontent}[correction]` where `n` is the number of lines at the beginning of the paragraph that remain untouched, and the optional `correction` is the number of supplementary lines that should be left or right indented, in case the box height is not exactly computed. In addition, there is an `\InsertC{boxcontent}`that `interrupts` a paragraph at the point of insertion, just terminating the current line, inserting the box contents centred on the page and resuming the parargraph afterwards.

I wrote once a very small `insbox.sty` file, that is a wrapper for `insbox.tex` and adds `\InsBoxO` and `\InsBoxI`macros (put on the outside or inside margin), that mimic the `o` and `i` options of the `wrapfigure`environments. Here is the code:

```
\ProvidesPackage{insbox}[2004/03/21 package wrapper for insbox.tex]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\input insbox
\newlength\insboxmargin
\insboxmargin=3mm
\makeatletter\@InsertBoxMargin=\insboxmargin\makeatother
\newcommand{\InsBoxO}[2]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\InsertBoxR{#1}{#2}}{\InsertBoxL{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\InsBoxI}[2]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\InsertBoxL{#1}{#2}}{\InsertBoxR{#1}{#2}}}
\makeatletter\newcommand{\resetmargin}{\@restore@}\makeatother
\endinput
```

For the problem of inserting figures in `lists environments`, you can see my answer (based on `insbox`) to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192348/wrapping-text-around-a-table-in-enumeration-environment-with-cutout-and-parshape/192443#192443).

To insert a caption, one must use the `threeparttable` environment and the `\captionof` command (from the `caption` package).

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{insbox, wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx, captdef, threeparttable, caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{2}
 \lipsum[1-2]
\verb+\InsertBoxR inserted here: +
 \InsertBoxR{10}{%
 \begin{threeparttable}
 \begin{tabular}{lrrr}
 \hline
 sgnj  & 0.31  & 1.16  & 1.16 \\     safd  & 0.46  & 0.91  & 0.99 \\     dsfv  & 0.42  & 0.78  & 0.56 \\     jl;;  & 0.35  & 1.18  & 1.47 \\     sdfd  & 0.38  & 0.76  & 0.79 \\     degf  & 0.27  & 1.29  & 1.33 \\     fewf  & 0.24  & 0.58  & 0.59 \\     werf  & 0.30  & 0.71  & 0.71 \\     fhjj  & 0.64  & 1.45  & 0.60 \\     wdff  & 0.45  & 1.16  & 0.79 \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \captionof{table}{My table}%\label{c_table3}
 \end{threeparttable}
 }[6]%
\lipsum [3-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\value{page}` isn't reliable, since your code may be put on the next page by the output routine; the satisfactory way of doing it is by using a label; i think the `zref` bundle has an appropriate module, but there are lots of other ways.

Comment: `\InsertBoxR{10}{\begin{table}[htbp]
\scriptsize
  \centering
  \caption{h;ghglj,,f}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
          & $h$   &  $P_r$  &  $sgsh$  \\
          & (fdsg) & (sg) & (sg)  \\
\hline
    ;ogi  & 0.27  & 1.29  & 1.33 \\
    ljkl  & 0.64  & 1.45  & 0.60 \\
    ljhg  & 0.45  & 1.16  & 0.79 \\
\hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{c_table3}%
\end{table}}`
tried to compile this using above sty file. didnt compile

Comment: @ankhi: You forgot a closing brace. See my updated answer, with your example and a precision about corrective term.

Comment: What is a threeparttable?? is it better than the normal table?............also what about figures in the box?

Comment: well I tried your code with a longer table and it made the main text half width for 3 pages :(

Comment: `threeparttable` is a package designed to allow footnotes in tables, that are placed at the bottom of the page. Here it is used because it measures the table width and allows inserting a caption. The problem with the longer table may come from the fact that this environment doesn't allow page breaks, and `tabular` doesn't either (you then should use the `longtable` environment). Could we have a Minimal (non)Working Example?