# window and experimental environment from chemmacros - compatibility?

Tags: errors, environments, incompatibility, chemistry, chemmacros

I am having a problem with the formatting of the experimental part of my chemistry thesis. I describe the synthesis and the spectroscopic values of a molecule to wrap around a small graphic representation of it.
In the beginning I used wrapfiqure like in the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{picinpar}                       
\usepackage{chemmacros}                     
\usechemmodule{spectroscopy}    
\begin{document}
\section{Experimental}
    \subsection{Ferrocene}
        \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.1\textwidth}
            \vspace{-10pt}
            \includegraphics{Fc.eps}
        \end{wrapfigure}        
        Ferrocene was prepared by slow addition of a solution of \ch{FeCl3} in DMSO to a mixture of freshly cracked cycopentadiene and potassium hydroxide in THF at \SI{-78}{\celsius}. %After complete addition the mixture was quenched with water and extracted with \ch{Et2O}, the org. layer was dried over \ch{MgSO4} and the solvent evaporated to leave an orange solid that could be purified by sublimation.
        \\
        \begin{experimental}[format=\bfseries, coupling-unit={},list=true]
            \NMR(500)[CDCl3] = 
                \val{9.25}  (   s,  \#{1},  \pos{1}     ),
                \val{8.23}  (   s,  \#{1},  \pos{2}     ),
                \val{8.01}  (   s,  \#{1},  \pos{3}     ),
                \val{7.77}  (   s,  \#{1},  \pos{3}     ),
                \val{6.20}  (   s,  \#{2},  \pos{4}     ),
                \val{5.48}  (   s,  \#{2},  \pos{6}     ),
                \val{4.26}  (   s,  \#{2},  \pos{5}     ),
                \val{2.71}  (   s,  \#{1},  \pos{8}     ),
                \val{1.80}  (   s,  \#{1},  \pos{9}     ).
        \\
            \NMR{13,C[^1H]}(126, MHz)[CDCl3] = 
                \val{165.0} (   s,  \#{1},  \pos{1}     ),
                \val{120.6} (   s,  \#{1},  \pos{2}     ),
                \val{119.0} (   s,  \#{1},  \pos{3}     ),
                \val{89.6}  (   s,  \#{1},  \pos{3}     ),
                \val{88.2}  (   s,  \#{2},  \pos{4}     ),
                \val{73.4}  (   s,  \#{2},  \pos{6}     ),
                \val{62.8}  (   s,  \#{2},  \pos{5}     ),
                \val{56.0}  (   s,  \#{1},  \pos{8}     ),
                \val{40.5}  (   s,  \#{1},  \pos{9}     ).
        \end{experimental}
\end{document}
```

It and it worked fine, until I started to realize, that very short descriptions lead to parts of the spectroscopy data aligning with the picture like this:

[image: Test]

So the way I was trying to circumvent this problem was by using a window environment (same packages):

```
\begin{document}
\section{Experimental}
    \subsection{Ferrocene}
    \begin{window}[0,r,\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{Fc.eps},{}]
        Ferrocene was prepared by slow addition of a solution of \ch{FeCl3} in DMSO to a mixture of freshly cracked cycopentadiene and potassium hydroxide in THF at \SI{-78}{\celsius}. %After complete addition the mixture was quenched with water and extracted with \ch{Et2O}, the org. layer was dried over \ch{MgSO4} and the solvent evaporated to leave an orange solid that could be purified by sublimation.
        \\

        \begin{experimental}[format=\bfseries, coupling-unit={},list=true]
            \NMR(500)[CDCl3] = 
                %same data as before
        \\
            \NMR{13,C[^1H]}(126, MHz)[CDCl3] = 
                %same data as before
        \end{experimental}
    \end{window}
\end{document}
```

which, however leaves me with the following type of errors:

> /TestExp2.tex:19: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. [          \NMR(500)[CDCl3]]

So obviously there seems to be an incompatibility of the window and experimental environment. If i `\end{window}` before `\begin{experimental}`, then it works fine, however the graphic then sometimes ends up being covered up by the text that follows, depending on its size.

So my question is: Is there a workaround, such that I can actually define a window that includes the experimental environment? Or is this impossible?

I am also open to alternative solutions that do not use `wrapfigure` OR `window`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would placing the small figure in the margin be a suitable result? `\marginpar{\includegraphics{graphicname}}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it would however not be a suitable solution for all possible figures, since some of them are quite broad (maybe three times as broad as in the example). So I'd rather find a solution that places the figure within the text.

Comment: For scientific reports, it is common to place figures with a caption as an independent entity and allow them to float around a little. This is much easier to handle and oriented to the big publishers around the world. Hard fixing a picture inside the text is rather uncommon because it is an incredible amount of work.

Comment: This happens with other lists (e.g. `description`), too, so it is not an issue of `chemmacros`, strictly speaking

Answer (score 1):

This approach is based on the answer posted here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309454, which is versatile for placement of figures in a range of environments.

The essential part of this method uses:

> a strut that places the baseline of the first text line at a specified distance from the top of a `minipage`. Then `adjustbox` to place the top of the minipage exactly that amount above the outer baseline.

In this instance, because of the use of the `experimental` environment from the `spectroscopy` module of the `chemmacros` package, it was necessary to place the two adjustboxes side by side. This is done using `minipage` as an inner environment to `adjustbox`, with one minipage set at `0.8\linewidth` and the other at `0.2\linewidth` (see section 4.10 of the `adjustbox` manual).

The following example shows two possible layouts for a drawing of the chemical molecule alongside the accompanying spectroscopic data.

*Updated 19 April 2017 to remove spaces from NMR specifications. See Clemens comment.*

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{spectroscopy} 
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newlength{\strutheight}
\settoheight{\strutheight}{\strut}

\begin{document}
\section{Experimental}
\subsection{Ferrocene layout 1}
Ferrocene was prepared by slow addition of a solution of \ch{FeCl3} in DMSO to a mixture of freshly cracked cycopentadiene and potassium hydroxide in THF at \SI{-78}{\celsius}.

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309454    
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T,raise=\strutheight,minipage={0.8\linewidth}}
        \begin{experimental}[format=\bfseries, coupling-unit={},list=true]
            \NMR(500)[CDCl3] = 
            \val{9.25}  (s,\#{1},\pos{1}),
            \val{8.23}  (s,\#{1},\pos{2}),
            \val{8.01}  (s,\#{1},\pos{3}),
            \val{7.77}  (s,\#{1},\pos{3}),
            \val{6.20}  (s,\#{2},\pos{4}),
            \val{5.48}  (s,\#{2},\pos{6}),
            \val{4.26}  (s,\#{2},\pos{5}),
            \val{2.71}  (s,\#{1},\pos{8}),
            \val{1.80}  (s,\#{1},\pos{9}).
            \NMR{13,C[^1H]}(126, MHz)[CDCl3] = 
            \val{165.0} (s,\#{1},\pos{1}),
            \val{120.6} (s,\#{1},\pos{2}),
            \val{119.0} (s,\#{1},\pos{3}),
            \val{89.6}  (s,\#{1},\pos{3}),
            \val{88.2}  (s,\#{2},\pos{4}),
            \val{73.4}  (s,\#{2},\pos{6}),
            \val{62.8}  (s,\#{2},\pos{5}),
            \val{56.0}  (s,\#{1},\pos{8}),
            \val{40.5}  (s,\#{1},\pos{9}).
        \end{experimental}   
\end{adjustbox}%
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=T,raise=\strutheight,minipage={0.2\linewidth}}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{2cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{fc.png}
    \end{wrapfigure}% 
    \strut{}
\end{adjustbox} 

\subsection{Ferrocene layout 2}
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=T,raise=\strutheight,minipage={0.8\linewidth}}
Ferrocene was prepared by slow addition of a solution of \ch{FeCl3} in DMSO to a mixture of freshly cracked cycopentadiene and potassium hydroxide in THF at \SI{-78}{\celsius}.

\begin{experimental}[format=\bfseries, coupling-unit={},list=true]
    \NMR(500)[CDCl3] = 
    \val{9.25}  (s,\#{1},\pos{1}),
    \val{8.23}  (s,\#{1},\pos{2}),
    \val{8.01}  (s,\#{1},\pos{3}),
    \val{7.77}  (s,\#{1},\pos{3}),
    \val{6.20}  (s,\#{2},\pos{4}),
    \val{5.48}  (s,\#{2},\pos{6}),
    \val{4.26}  (s,\#{2},\pos{5}),
    \val{2.71}  (s,\#{1},\pos{8}),
    \val{1.80}  (s,\#{1},\pos{9}).
\end{experimental}   
\end{adjustbox}%
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=T,raise=\strutheight,minipage={0.2\linewidth}}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{2cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{fc.png}
    \end{wrapfigure}% 
    \strut{}
\end{adjustbox}%
\begin{experimental}[format=\bfseries, coupling-unit={},list=true]
    \NMR{13,C[^1H]}(126, MHz)[CDCl3] = 
    \val{165.0} (s,\#{1},\pos{1}),
    \val{120.6} (s,\#{1},\pos{2}),
    \val{119.0} (s,\#{1},\pos{3}),
    \val{89.6}  (s,\#{1},\pos{3}),
    \val{88.2}  (s,\#{2},\pos{4}),
    \val{73.4}  (s,\#{2},\pos{6}),
    \val{62.8}  (s,\#{2},\pos{5}),
    \val{56.0}  (s,\#{1},\pos{8}),
    \val{40.5}  (s,\#{1},\pos{9}).
\end{experimental} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You (and the OP) shouldn't have those spaces in `(   s,  \#{2},  \pos{6}     ),` (look at the second to last line in the image of your code…)

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I posted the question and I just wanted to add my current work-around, since this seems to be a general problem that cannot be properly resolved. This may give an idea to people with a similar problem. So what I did now is, wherever I got this wrong alignment in my experimental parts, I introduced a tabular environment before the experimental. This is how the code then looks:

```
    \begin{table}[h!]
            \begin{tabular}{@{} p{0.8\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth} @{}}
            Ferrocene was prepared by slow addition of a solution of \ch{FeCl3} in DMSO to a mixture of freshly cracked cycopentadiene and potassium hydroxide in THF at \SI{-78}{\celsius}.  & \\raisebox{-0.8\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Fc.eps}} \\
            \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \begin{experimental}[format=\bfseries, coupling-unit={},list=true]
        \NMR(500)[CDCl3] = 
            %same data as before
        \\
        \NMR{13,C[^1H]}(126, MHz)[CDCl3] = 
            %same data as before
    \end{experimental}
```

This makes the result look the way I wanted it, so I will stick with this solution although it is not very elegant, except somebody proposes a much better way of doing it...