# wrapfig within linguex

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure, linguex

I'm trying to wrap an image within a `linguex` bullet, but the image does not compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex, graphicx, wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\ex. bla bla bla \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image}\end{wrapfigure} 

\end{document}
```

Notice that I need the `wrapfigure` environment to be on the same line as the `\ex.` argument, otherwise it wouldn't compile. I feel like that's some sort of incompatibility between the two packages, but does anybody know if there is a way-around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few solutions around for placing figures in list environments. The following uses the answer published here: [Will it ever be possible to use wrapfig with an enumerate or itemize environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59101/will-it-ever-be-possible-to-use-wrapfig-with-an-enumerate-or-itemize-environment/309454#309454)

The only difference is the use of the `\ex` macro versus the `enumerate` environment. Quoting from the referenced solution:

> It is possible by putting the `wrapfigure` into a `parbox` or `minipage` as is mentioned in some of the duplicates of this question. However those methods usually fix vertical spacing issues by manually inserting `\vspace` with hand picked values. This solution works automatically by using a strut (`\strut`). The strut places the baseline of the first text line at a specified distance from the top of the `minipage`. Then `adjustbox` is used to place the top of the `minipage` exactly that amount above the outer baseline.

The MWE and result are as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{linguex, graphicx, wrapfig}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\newlength{\strutheight}
\settoheight{\strutheight}{\strut}

\begin{document}

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59101/will-it-ever-be-possible-to-use-wrapfig-with-an-enumerate-or-itemize-environment/309454#309454
\ex. \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T,raise=\strutheight,minipage={1.0\linewidth}}
        \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \captionof{figure}{My caption}
        \end{wrapfigure}% 
        \strut{}\lipsum[2]
    \end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

This is a response to OP's comment:

> Is it then possible to have a figure wrapped in more than one \ex. environment?

I have to guess a bit to interpret what is requested. Here is an interpretation with multiple figures at different levels of environments.

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{linguex, graphicx, wrapfig}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\newlength{\strutheight}
\settoheight{\strutheight}{\strut}

\begin{document}

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59101/will-it-ever-be-possible-to-use-wrapfig-with-an-enumerate-or-itemize-environment/309454#309454
\ex. \lipsum[2]
\a. \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T,raise=\strutheight,minipage={1.0\linewidth}}
        \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \captionof{figure}{My caption}
        \end{wrapfigure}% 
        \strut{}\lipsum[2]
    \end{adjustbox}
\b. \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T,raise=\strutheight,minipage={1.0\linewidth}}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \captionof{figure}{My caption}
    \end{wrapfigure}% 
    \strut{}\lipsum[2]
    \end{adjustbox}
    \a. \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T,raise=\strutheight,minipage={1.0\linewidth}}
        \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \captionof{figure}{My caption}
        \end{wrapfigure}% 
        \strut{}\lipsum[2]
    \end{adjustbox}
    \b.\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! Is it then possible to have a figure wrapped in more than one `\ex.` environment?

Comment: @RobertP If I interpret your question correctly, the answer is yes. Other solutions are possible using the `cutwin`, which has the advantage of determining where the figure is placed in the itemized paragraph. However, if those types of customizations are not required, this works out-of-the box in all the list environments and classes (including `Beamer`) where I have used it.