# How to insert a picture next to the itemize

Tags: itemize, wrapfigure

How to insert a picture next to the itemize by wrapfig?? Like this: [image]

I try this:

```
\subsection*{1. Persona}
\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{2.5in}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2in]{fig/person.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Jméno} - Adam
\item \textbf{Pohlaví} - muž
\item \textbf{Věk} - 21 let
\item \textbf{Stav} - svobodný, bezdětný
\item \textbf{Práce} - student vysoké školy (Vysoké učení technické fakulta podnikatelská)\end{itemize}`
```

But it looks bad:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you read the `wrapfig` manual, especially the part that `wrapfigure` should not be used in `list` - like environment, e.g. `itemize` etc.?

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't a strength of TeX.

Comment: And is there any solution to my problem? Or not?

Comment: @MarekVrchlický http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59101/will-it-ever-be-possible-to-use-wrapfig-with-an-enumerate-or-itemize-environment might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 9):

With package `picins` which is not part of TeXLive (license issue). Get it from CTAN: http://ctan.org/pkg/picins

```
\parpic(width,height)(x-offset,y-offset)[options][position]{image}
```

Only the `{image}` is mandatory, all other arguments are optional.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{1. Persona}

\begin{itemize}
    \parpic(2in,1.5in)[r]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{tiger}}
    \item \textbf{Jméno} - Adam
    \item \textbf{Pohlaví} - muž
    \item \textbf{Věk} - 21 let
    \item \textbf{Stav} - svobodný, bezdětný
    \item \textbf{Práce} - student vysoké školy (Vysoké učení technické fakulta 
    podnikatelská)
    \item \blindtext    
\end{itemize}`

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround, using `enumitem` and the `insbox` plain TeX macro package.

With enumitem, you can change the right margin of a list, choosing the number of items which correspond to the height of the graphics you want to insert, use the `\InsertBoxR` command *before* the list, then use  the `resume` key in a new list. Some minor adjustment of vertical spacing between the two lists has to be done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
\usepackage{graphicx, enumitem}%
 \input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{1. Persona}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. More text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text.


\begin{itemize}[before=\setlength{\rightmargin}{2in}\vspace*{-\dimexpr\topsep + \partopsep}
\InsertBoxR{0}{\raisebox{-\dimexpr\height+\topsep+\partopsep+\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics{euclid}}}, after=\vspace{\dimexpr\itemsep-\topsep}]
  \item \textbf{Jméno} - Adam
  \item \textbf{Pohlaví} - muž
  \item \textbf{Věk} - 21 let
  \item \textbf{Stav} - svobodný, bezdětný
  \item \textbf{Práce} - student vysoké školy (Vysoké učení technické fakulta podnikatels
  \item \textbf{Stav} - svobodný, bezdětný
  \item \textbf{Práce} - student vysoké školy (Vysoké učení technické fakulta podnikatels
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[topsep = 0pt]%
  \item \textbf{Práce} - student vysoké školy (Vysoké učení technické fakulta podnikatels
  \item \textbf{Práce} - student vysoké školy (Vysoké učení technické fakulta podnikatels
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]