# How to include a floating image at the left of an itemize?

Tags: itemize, wrapfigure, wrap, wrapfig

I've been having some problems with "wrapfigure". I'm supposed to fix this with `{L}` instead of `{l}` (
[Source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56176/handling-of-wrapfig-pictures-in-latex)) but it doesn't work because of the bullets.

[image: Screenshot]

Code:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{5cm}  
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=5 cm,keepaspectratio=true]{pics/modelos_atomicos.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: Related: [Will it ever be possible to use wrapfig with an enumerate or itemize environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59101/134144), [Problem with wrapfig and itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208429/134144) and [How to insert a picture next to the itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349857/134144)

Comment: To sum it up, the use of `wrapfigure` in lists like `itemize` and `enumerate` are not supported.