# A blank appears for no reason

Tags: itemize

So I'm working on a report, but after adding a second item `\item \underline{\textbf{Réalisation expérimentale }}` a blank appears on the right of my text like it shows on the image. [image: blank on item 2]

ans here's the code :

```
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[6]{r}{4cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{CR.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \underline{\textbf{Charge résistive}}
\smallbreak
\textbf{O}n réalise le circuit de charge résistive en utilisant le transformateur, thyristor et résistance. En premier temps,on va visualiser la tenion aux bornes de la charge $V_C$ , la tension aux bornes du thyristor $V_T$ et le courant qui traverse la charge $I_C$ par rapport à la tension de source $V_S$, pour un angle d'amorçage $\alpha=60$. Ensuite, on mesure le courant aux bornes de la charge $I_C$ et sa valeur efficace $I_{eff}$, la tension aux bornes de la charge $V_C$ et sa valeur efficace $V_{eff}$ pour différents angles d'amorçage ($\alpha=10$,$\alpha=60$ et $\alpha=90$), et on discute les résultats.\\
\item \underline{\textbf{Réalisation expérimentale }}
\smallbreak
Pour la réalisation pratique, on va réaliser le circuit sur un\textit{Leybold Ditactic}. La différence majeure entre la simulation et la réalisation pratique, c'est que l'angle d'amorçage à partir du quel on peut visualiser l'effet du thyristor est supérieure à $\alpha=10$.\\
On va visualiser la tension aux bornes de la charge $V_C$ par rapport à la tension source $V_S$, pour l'angle d'amorçage égale à $\alpha=90$.

\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `wrapfig` does not work well when used in combination with lists such as `enumerate`.

Comment: From the `wrapfig` documentation: "You must not specify a wrapfigure in any type of list environment or  immediately before or immediately after one. It is OK to follow a list if there is a blank line (\par) in between."

Comment: check this post please (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59101/120578) [not only the accepted but the other answers too]

Comment: I think this question isn't about `wrapfig`, but about the space at the end of the text of section 2, where the underline is longer than it needs to be.  The space is in the input, before the close braces in "`expérimentale }}`".  Get rid of it.

Comment: One way to avoid this problem is to split the `enumerate` environment. Then TeX will typeset the paragraph the right way.

Answer (score -1):

in your example you write

```
\item \underline{\textbf{Réalisation expérimentale }}
```

Maybe the space before the first closing curly bracket is causing your problem.

Comment: hm, you just repeat the @barbara beeton comment ...