# Move the image within a list that flows around it

Tags: wrapfigure

I am trying to flow a list around an image, I found the following example in the comment located at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309454/168506):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
  
  \newlength{\strutheight}
  \settoheight{\strutheight}{\strut}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item
      \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T,raise=\strutheight,minipage={\linewidth}}
        \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
          \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
        \end{wrapfigure}
        \strut{}\lipsum[2]
      \end{adjustbox}
    \item \lipsum[1]
  \end{enumerate}
  
\end{document}
```

Although the image is embedded in one of the list items (and I wanted the image unbound to the list), the code in that question works in all the cases I have tested.

However, I would like to move the image from the left side to the right side, but I simply don't understand enough about the packages used.

I would be grateful for any direction.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `wrapfigure` specification from `l` (for left) to `r` (for right).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
  
  \newlength{\strutheight}
  \settoheight{\strutheight}{\strut}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item
      \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T,raise=\strutheight,minipage={\linewidth}}
        \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
          \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
        \end{wrapfigure}
        \strut{}\lipsum[2]
      \end{adjustbox}
    \item \lipsum[1]
  \end{enumerate}
  
\end{document}
```