# Minipage inside itemize, bullet point position

Tags: itemize, minipage

Sometimes I wish to include a small diagram next to the text which I could achieve by using two mini-page, one for the text, one for the diagram. However when I use it inside itemize, the bullet point gone to the wrong place (see diagram). How can I make it so that the bullet point is in the right place (ie. next to "An")[image]

In response to Ulrike Fischer's answer, for example the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item blbl

\item \begin{minipage}{4cm} some text\\some text\\some text\end{minipage}

\item \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm} some text\\some text\\some text\\some text\\some text\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}   
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [->] (-1,-1) -- (1,-1) -- (1, 1) -- (-1, 1) -- (-1,-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}

\item \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm} some text\\some text\\some text\\some text\\some text\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{4cm}   
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [->] (-1,-1) -- (1,-1) -- (1, 1) -- (-1, 1) -- (-1,-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

so the tikz diagram is not next to the text.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Not easy: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53702/wrapping-text-in-enumeration-environment-around-a-table, and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59101/will-it-ever-be-possible-to-use-wrapfig-with-an-enumerate-or-itemize-environment

Comment: Did you try adding the optional `[t]` to the minipages? Other than that, it can be done without minipages with some code involving the `insbox` set of plain macros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [t] option to align your minipage at the first line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item blbl

\item \begin{minipage}{4cm} some text\\some text\\some text\end{minipage}

\item \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm} some text\\some text\\some text\end{minipage}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

You can align the following minipage with the tikzpicture e.g. with a \vspace or by using the baseline key of tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item blbl

\item \begin{minipage}{4cm} some text\\some text\\some text\end{minipage}

\item \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm} some text\\some text\\some text\\some text\\some text\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(1,1)}] %or some other coordinate
      \draw [->] (-1,-1) -- (1,-1) -- (1, 1) -- (-1, 1) -- (-1,-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\item \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm} some text\\some text\\some text\\some text\\some text\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
 \centering
 \vspace{-\ht\strutbox} %or some other value.
     \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [->] (-1,-1) -- (1,-1) -- (1, 1) -- (-1, 1) -- (-1,-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but then the other mini-page containing the diagram went to the wrong place (i.e. not on the same level as the mini-page containing the text) How could I fixed it? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the content of the other minipage. Where is its baseline?

Comment: Sorry I am new to Latex, not sure what baseline exactly is. The other mini-page usually contains a tikz diagram and the diagram are meant to be next to the text.

Comment: BTW, itemize sets the left margin using \leftskip, in which case \linewidth=\textwidth-\leftskip represents the remaining space.

Comment: Extend my code with an small example diagram and include this in your question.

Comment: I added an example!

Comment: I added an edit.