# Wrapping text in enumeration environment around a table in tikzposter

Tags: enumerate, itemize, wrapfigure, tikzposter

The goal of simply using `wrapfigure` to wrap text around a table, is not achieved if the text contains `enumerate` of `itemize` environment.

However, some time ago, the accepted answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53702/wrapping-text-in-enumeration-environment-around-a-table/53715?noredirect=1#comment817396_53715) showed how to do that in the case of `\documentclass{article}`. Here is the minimized MWE that includes the solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Subsection}

\savebox0{%
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hline    
        Size        &   Color   &   Target2 \\
        \hline
        XS      &   green   &   Yes     \\
        L       &   green   &   Yes     \\
        XS      &   white   &   No      \\
        M       &   black   &   No      \\
        XL      &   green   &   Yes     \\
        XS      &   white   &   Yes     \\
        L       &   black   &   No      \\
        M       &   green   &   Yes     \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \makeatletter
        \dimen@\wd0
        \advance\dimen@2em
        \advance\rightmargin-\dimen@
        \advance\linewidth-\dimen@
        \parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
        \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vtop to \z@{\vskip1em \box\z@\vss}}
        \item

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
        Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
        Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
        Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
        Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
        Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
        Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
        Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
        Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
        Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
        Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.


        \advance\rightmargin\dimen@
        \advance\linewidth\dimen@
        \parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth

        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
        Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
        Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
        Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
        Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.
    \end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: Code output]

However, I have now two issues:

- the solution does not work perfectly: if an item is long (see the first item), the fixed width of an item is not desirable
- I want to wrap some text around a table in `\documentclass{tikzposter}`. However, changing `\documentclass{article}` to `\documentclass{tikzposter}` results in a bunch of errors.

Comment: I  have a solution based on `insbox`, but it works only in the article class.